# Html Multiple Select items Selected issue

Tags: php, html

I have a form with multiple select items. I can select multiple items. But how do I select those items which I initially selected, if I wrongly input other fields of the form with PHP ?

```
<select name="interest[]" class="tr5" multiple="multiple">
<option value="">Select..</option>
<option value="art">Art</option>
<option value="litteratures">Litteratures</option>
<option value="business" >Business</option>    
<option value="internet" >Internet</option>    
</select>
```

I can do this without **multiple tag** with php.

```
<option value="internet" <?php if(isset($_POST['interest']) && $_POST['interest'] == 
"internet") echo 'selected = "selected"';?>>Internet</option>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I understand your question then you do it just like you propose; but I imagine it would be done inside a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<option value="internet" <?php if(isset($_POST['interest']) &&
in_array("internet",$_POST['interest'])) echo 'selected = "selected"';?>>Internet</option>
```

Comment: @AlexMojum: you are welcome, it's a pleasure to know it helps